Incompatibility with react-native-gesture-handler
This is the project's enviorenment on which I am having trouble build the app.
React Native version: 0.76.5
Java version: 17

I have done these:
yarn install
...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 68.90s.

yarn add redux redux-saga
...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 9 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ redux-saga@1.3.0
└─ redux@5.0.1
info All dependencies
├─ @redux-saga/core@1.3.0
├─ @redux-saga/deferred@1.2.1
├─ @redux-saga/delay-p@1.2.1
├─ @redux-saga/is@1.1.3
├─ redux-saga@1.3.0
├─ redux@5.0.1
├─ typescript-compare@0.0.2
├─ typescript-logic@0.0.0
└─ typescript-tuple@2.2.1
Done in 5.65s.

yarn add @react-navigation/native react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-vector-icons
...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 19 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ @react-navigation/native@7.0.14
├─ react-native-gesture-handler@2.21.2
├─ react-native-reanimated@3.16.6
├─ react-native-safe-area-context@5.0.0
├─ react-native-screens@4.4.0
└─ react-native-vector-icons@10.2.0
info All dependencies
├─ @egjs/hammerjs@2.0.17
├─ @react-navigation/core@7.3.1
├─ @react-navigation/native@7.0.14
├─ @react-navigation/routers@7.1.2
├─ @types/hammerjs@2.0.46
├─ decode-uri-component@0.2.2
├─ filter-obj@1.1.0
├─ hoist-non-react-statics@3.3.2
├─ query-string@7.1.3
├─ react-freeze@1.0.4
├─ react-native-gesture-handler@2.21.2
├─ react-native-reanimated@3.16.6
├─ react-native-safe-area-context@5.0.0
├─ react-native-screens@4.4.0
├─ react-native-vector-icons@10.2.0
├─ split-on-first@1.1.0
├─ strict-uri-encode@2.0.0
├─ use-sync-external-store@1.4.0
└─ warn-once@0.1.1
Done in 9.99s.

cat package.json
{
  "name": "pokemonApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.14",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.21.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.16.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^4.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.25.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.76.5",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.76.5",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.76.5",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.76.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}

cat android/build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "35.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 35
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.24"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"

cat android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-all.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

cat node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/build.gradle
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeBuildJsonTask

buildscript {
    def kotlin_version = rootProject.ext.has('kotlinVersion') ? rootProject.ext.get('kotlinVersion') : project.properties['RNGH_kotlinVersion']

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1")
        classpath("com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-plugin-gradle:6.7.2")
    }
}

...

The build complains that the gradle (or gradle plugin) needed for react-native-gesture-handler not found.
react-native run-android
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-gesture-handler'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-gesture-handler:classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2.1/gradle-7.2.1.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2.1/gradle-7.2.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :react-native-gesture-handler

cd android;
./gradlew clean --refresh-dependencies
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'pokemonApp'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.6.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.6.0/gradle-8.6.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.6.0/gradle-8.6.0.pom
     Required by:
         root project :
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.6.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.6.0/gradle-8.6.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.6.0/gradle-8.6.0.pom
     Required by:
         root project : > project :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin

I am totally stuck.
